# django: how to annotate queryset with count of foreignkey reverse after Trunc?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A',  verbose_name='bs')

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A',  verbose_name='cs')
```

I want to count the number of B and C by A and group them.

Here is my attempt, but the result is not correct.

```
from django.db.models import  Count, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc

a_qs = A.objects.filter(Q(created_on__gte=start_date, created_on__lte=end_date))
g = a_qs.objects.annotate(time=Trunc('created_on', 'month')).values('time').order_by('time')

result = g.annotate(a_total=Count('id'), b_total=Count('bs'), c_total=Count('cs'))
```

Although this will not report an error, the result will be incorrect. I don't want to loop queryset.

I have an idea that can meet my needs, but in the end I need to merge queryset.

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(Q(created_on__gte=start_date, created_on__lte=end_date))

a_g = a_qs.annotate(time=Trunc('created_on', 'month')).values('time').order_by('time')
a_result = a_g.annotate(a_total=Count('id'))

b_g = B.objects.filter(a__in=a_qs).annotate(time=Trunc('a__created_on', 'month')).values('time').order_by('time')
b_result = b_g.annotate(b_total=Count('id'))

c_g = ...
c_result = ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that you make *two* JOINs, and thus the JOINs act as a "multiplier" of each other. You can count the *distinct* related objects with:

```
A.objects.filter(
    created_on__range=(start_date, end_date)
).annotate(
    time=Trunc('created_on', 'month')
).values('time').annotate(
    a_total=Count('id', distinct=True),
    b_total=Count('b', distinct=True),
    c_total=Count('c', distinct=True)
).order_by('time')
```

Comment: can it be done in prefetch_related or select_related models also? I have tried but the result shows None. Any hints? @Willem

Comment: @M.A.K.Simanto: well this will return a `QuerySet` of *dictionaries*, so both `.select_related` and `.prefetch_related` do not make much sense. If you do this without the truncate, the groups will be individual `A` objects, so no.